# C# multithreading

Tags: c#, thread-safety, properties

Can `ICollection<T>.Count` property getter be considered atomic *(and, therefore, `threadsafe`)?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *completely* depends on the collection; `ICollection<T>` is just an interface.

Every collection that I know of simply returns an `Int32` field in its `Count` getter, so it usually is atomic.
However, there is never a guarantee that the count didn't change just after you fetched the property.

Answer (score 7):

No, as you can only make that assumption for implementations, not an interface.

Answer (score 3):

- Atomic would only make sense for **implementation** and **not interface**. You could have two implementations: one non-thread-safe implementation one thread safe.
- `List<T>` is not thread safe since it does not use `InterLocked`.

Comment: How would using `Interlocked` make the `List<T>` implementation of `Count` thread-safe? The `Count` property just returns an `int` field, which is an atomic read. Of course, there's always the possibility that the count is already stale by the time it's returned to the caller, but that's just as likely if `Interlocked` was used.